# Can I make a Java HttpServer threaded/process requests in parallel?

Tags: java, httpserver

I have built a simple HttpServer following tutorials i have found online, using Sun's lightweight HttpServer.

Basically the main function looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        //Create the context for the server.
        server.createContext("/", new BaseHandler());

        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }
```

And I have implemented the BaseHandler Interface's method to process the Http request and return a response.

```
static class BaseHandler implements HttpHandler {
        //Handler method
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {

          //Implementation of http request processing
          //Read the request, get the parameters and print them
          //in the console, then build a response and send it back.
        }
  }
```

I have also created a Client that sends multiple requests via threads. Each thread sends the following request to the server:

> http://localhost:8000/[context]?int="+threadID

On Each client run, The requests seem to arrive in different order to the server, but they are served in a serial manner.

What i wish to acomplish is for the requests to be processed in a parallel manner if that is possible.

Is it possible, for example, to run each handler in a seperate thread, and if so, is it a good thing to do.

Or should i just drop using Sun's lightweight server altogether and focus an building something from scratch?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's what the HttpServer already does.

Comment: This is done by setting the executor, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html?is-external=true

Comment: If this is anything but a learning project, I would recommend looking at libraries like [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/) or [Netty](https://netty.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies everyone! I will look more into it asap.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As you can see in [ServerImpl](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/httpserver/ServerImpl.java.html), the default executor just "run" the task :

```
  157       private static class DefaultExecutor implements Executor {
  158           public void execute (Runnable task) {
  159               task.run();
  160           }
  161       }
```

you must provide a real executor for your httpServer, like that :

```
server.setExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
```

and your server will run in parallel.
Carefull, this is a non-limited Executor, see [Executors.newFixedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) to limit the number of Thread.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I will look more into executors and see if i can understand better :)

Comment: Quick question though: does the executor replace the handler now in a sense or is something different?

Comment: no, only the way to "serve" task. With a newCahdedThreadPool(), it will create as many thread as request. But your handler will be called as usual. Take care, if you reuse the same handler, he must be ThreadSafe.

Comment: Looks like it works just fine with newFixedThreadPool, but i will need to study more about executors. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: @twillouer Is this server synchronous or asynchronous ? As Http is a synchronous, I want to know how this server behaves.

Comment: @Hoysala the server is synchronous : he listen on port, accept the socket and start a new thread

Answer (score 2):

You used server.setExecutor(**null**) that runs the handler in the same caller thread. In this case, the main thread which runs the server.

You only need to change the line as

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
    //Create the context for the server.
    server.createContext("/", new BaseHandler());
    server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    server.start();
}
```